# Bit shifting in IBM assembler

Tags: assembly, bit-manipulation, mainframe

In IBM OS/390 assembly, I am trying to do the following:

I have a set of bits that all end in 2 zeroes:

```
00xxxxxx 00yyyyyy 00zzzzzz
```

I want to compress them into the following format:

```
xxxxxxyy yyyyzzzz zz...
```

I figure that the order will something like

```
ICM  R7,B'1111',FIRSTBUF       LOAD 4 BYTES FROM FIRSTBUF INTO REGISTER 7
SLL  R7,2                      SHIFT ALL BITS LEFT BY 2
STCM R7,B'1000',FINALBUF       PASTE THE LEFTMOST BYTE ONLY
SLL  R7,2                      SHIFT ALL BITS LEFT BY 2
(somehow overwrite only the rightmost 2 bits of the leftmost byte)
STCM R7,B'0100',FINALBUF       PASTE SECOND LEFTMOST BYTE
SLL  R7,2                      SHIFT ALL BITS LEFT BY 2
(somehow overwrite only the right 4 bits of the second byte)
STCM R7,B'0010',FINALBUF       PASTE SECOND RIGHTMOST BYTE
SLL  R7,2                      SHIFT ALL BITS LEFT BY 2
....
```

Am I on the right track here?

Comment: I believe you are looking for an "or" type op-code

Comment: Actually a simple load and store under mask. No shifting or or-ing needed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
ICM  R7,B'1111',FIRSTBUF       LOAD 4 BYTES FROM FIRSTBUF INTO REGISTER 7

SLL  R7,2       ; Shift away zeros
LR   R8,R7       ; Move to a work register
AND  R8, 0x3F   ; Clear out extra bits.
; First Character complete.

SLL  R7,8       ; Remove 1 character and lower 2 bit 0s by shifting away.
LR   R9,R7       ; Move to another work register
AND  R9, 0x3F    ; Clear out extra bits.
SLL  R9, 6       ; Shift up to proper location
O    R8, R9      ; Drop it in
; Second Character complete.

SLL  R7,8       ; Remove 1 character and lower 2 bit 0s by shifting away.
LR   R9,R7       ; Move to register
AND  R9, 0x3F    ; Clear out extra bits.
SLL  R9, 14      ; Shift up to proper location
O    R8, R9      ; Drop it in
; Third Character complete.

SLL  R7,8        ; Remove 1 character and lower 2 bit 0s by shifting away.
LR   R9,R7       ; Move to register
AND  R9, 0x3F    ; Clear out extra bits.
SLL  R9, 22      ; Shift up to proper location
O    R8, R9      ; Drop it in

; And so on until you want to store the result, or your holder register is full.
```

I have not coded in this assembler before, but one assembler is a lot like another and the above should demonstrate the ideas of bit manipulation with bitwise and/or combined with shifting.  It also buffers I/O by not constatnly writing data to memory, instead using registers to speed things up.

Good luck!

Comment: `O` is actually the mnemonic for the register-memory operation. Register-register is `OR`, at least as far as I can tell.

Comment: More than likely, you are correct - I went off the IBM pdf I found, but without any sort of assembler to tell me what I did wrong, I'm hoping that the concept of and/or/shift is what comes through to OP, as well as avoiding excessive writes to memory.

Comment: I'm a little confused on syntax here...is 0x3F supposed to be 3 bytes where all bits are set to 1?

Comment: @user3856804 yes, it is supposed to be that. Actual code will be slightly different.

Comment: If you are interested further, there is this, http://www.z390.org/, perhaps a couple of others as well. The bible for this is the *Principles of Operation*, current is *z/Architechture*, original is *System/360* which you can still locate by search-engineing. Several more in between. Not a bad shot, but if there is a some-type-of-load instruction it is one of a pair, the other being some-type-of-a-store.  Insert Characters (under) Mask points to the existence of Store Characters (under) Mask, which does what is needed in this case.

Answer (score 3):

As a die-hard assembler lover, I was going to offer a slight variation on the example above...

First, if you have available registers and can arrange for the original values to be adjacent in memory, a simple LOAD MULTIPLE (LM Rx,Ry,data) and three STORE CHARACTERS UNDER MASK (STCM) would do the trick. Total of four instructions.

But then it occurred to me that there's an even better way to do this with a single instruction using TRANSLATE (TR):

```
IN1    DC  A(0)                      <- Input fields...they must be contiguous   
IN2    DC  A(0)
IN3    DC  A(0)
     . . .
TARGET DC  XL9'010203050607090A0B'   <- Note the pattern
     . . .
       TR  TARGET,IN1                <- Magic!
```

The TRANSLATE instruction replaces values in the target using the second operand as a lookup table. While this is most commonly used for things like transforming ASCII to EBCDIC, it can also be used to "rearrange" data, much as the original poster wanted. TR takes the first byte (X'01'), indexes into the second operand by this amount, and replaces the value in the input with whatever it finds. When the instruction completes, the TARGET field contains exactly what's requested - and this approach only consumes a single CPU instruction.

I rarely get to show off my knowledge of mainframe assembler, so thanks for giving me the opportunity!

Comment: Excellent. Not many Assembler questions here. More, but not many more, at www.ibmmainframes.com if you want to jump in any time. There's also an Assembler group on LinkedIn, where some very good people hang out (not me, I stretched to misread the question :-) ).

Comment: Pity. There are folks that elevate assembler to an art form...there's so much to learn from this sort of question, and the people who really, really know this stuff are disappearing at an alarming rate.

Comment: Unless that's a picture of your granddaughter you'll be around a while yet. I've been putting off attempting a fix on my answer for weeks. I was so relieved someone had posted a new answer, I only read the last two paragraphs from the bottom up. For the actual question, my answer is useless since I misread the question. I fear that you've improved on my answer... but...

Comment: TR is the most useful /360 instruction ... right after LA :))

Answer (score 2):

I know you were asking about OS/390 architecture.  But if you are running on a z10 or later machine the ROTATE AND INSERT SELECTED BITS (RISBG) may be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

I think you've gone around the houses a bit on this.

```
BUF01    DS    CL4                First data location
...
BUF02    DS    CL4                Second data location
...
BUF03    DS    CL4                Third data location
...
FINBUF   DS    0CL9               Final location
FINB01   DS    CL3                First final part
FINB02   DS    CL3                Second final part
FINB03   DS    CL3                Third final part

         L     R7,BUF01          Load first data to available gp register    
         STCM  R7,B'0111',FINB01 Store low-order three where needed

         L     R7,BUF02          Load second data to available gp register    
         STCM  R7,B'0111',FINB02 Store low-order three where needed

         L     R7,BUF03          Load third data to available gp register    
         STCM  R7,B'0111',FINB03 Store low-order three where needed
         ETVOILA                 Required data arrives at this point in FINBUF
```

If your data (or any of it) happens to already be in registers, ditch the LOAD and change the `R7` to the appropriate register.

The advantage of `ICM` with `B'1111'`, which you have used in your question, is that it sets the Condition Code, a LOAD does not. If you do not need the CC, then ICM is slower than LOAD, so you'd not use it.

Here, there is no problem with blindly loading four bytes to a register, then storing the low-order three. Lots of variations possible, but no reason to keep it other than simple.

The entire four bytes are loaded into the register. Only the three low-order bytes of the register are stored in memory, due to the mask being B'0111'. Any bytes from the register which correspond to a 1 in the mask will be stored contiguously starting at the address of the second operand. You get your contiguous nine bytes by just not storing the first byte ever. No need for shift and then combine.

Here is an extract from the explanation of the *Store Characters Under Mask (STCM)* instruction, from page 313 of *Chapter 7. General Instructions* of the current (from the z/OS 2.1 *elements and features* page linking to documentation) *z/Architecture Principles of Operation*, which is your reference guide for Mainframe Assembler.

> Bytes selected from general register R(1) under control of a mask are
> placed at contiguous byte locations beginning at the second-operand
> address.
>
> The contents of the M(3) field are used as a
> mask. These four bits, left to right, correspond one for one with four
> bytes, left to right, of general register R(1). For STORE CHARACTERS
> UNDER MASK (STCM, STCMY), the four bytes to which the mask bits correspond > are in bit positions 32-63 of general register R(1)... The bytes
> corresponding
> to ones in the mask are placed in the same order at successive and
> contiguous storage locations beginning at the second-operand address.
> When the mask is not zero, the length of the second operand is equal
> to the number of ones in the mask. The contents of the general
> register remain unchanged.

Note, your CPU may not be the latest, but the description and use of all the instructions in your question will be the same. Ask your Technical Support which POP (Principles of Operation) you should use to match your actual CPU.

Comment: Ah, we got an expert here instead of my generic attempt.  OP should be following this example more than mine as, again, I was pulling from external knowledge and not working knowledge of this platform :)  Thank you!

Comment: No, but thanks. someone who writes BAL or HLASM would kick my posterior :-) The COBOL compiler generates machine code so you get to visit the *Principles of Operation* if you're interested enough.

Comment: Nah. I do ARM stuff now if I have to, but mostly get to stay higher level these days.  I will say that this assembler felt a bit over-engineered compared to the RISC stuff I learned over time.  Of course, everything gets more complex over time, even ARM :)

Comment: Bear in mind that the base instruction set is over 50 years old :-) Many, many new instructions, especially over last 15 years. Some new ones only last January. Certainly CISC.

Comment: Correct me if I'm wrong, but wouldn't this instruction do the following:

    00wwwwww 00xxxxxx 00yyyyyy 00zzzzzz

becomes

   00xxxxxx 00yyyyyy 00zzzzzz

? How does it move the zeroes over?

Comment: It doesn't move the zeros over. It just ignores them, and doesn't store them in the destination. That's what the mask does. B'0111' says "ignore the first byte, store the second byte, store the third byte, store the fourth byte". The leading X'00' just isn't there anymore in the result, just nine contiguous bytes of the three low-order bytes from the three sources.

Comment: @user3856804 I've updated the answer to include a quote from the manual and some further explanation. You should test before asking for correction, then you won't have to. If your question is actually about shifting, then you should ask a new one and not present a task which is more adequately served by other instructions.

Comment: @BillWoodger I think you've misunderstood the question. The question was asking how to take a sequence of 6-bit numbers stored unpacked in separate bytes and pack them together into a bitstream across bytes. So four 6-bit numbers stored in four bytes should end being packed together into only three bytes of storage.

Comment: @RossRidge You are only 100% correct. Although I'm not sure about four, but that's just quibbling. Thanks. Now I'll have to fudge some more Assembler.

Comment: A small alternative, if you can arrange for the original values to be adjacent in memory:

Answer (score 0):

```
* ASSUME R1 -> TWO ENTRY PARM LIST
* PARM ONE -> 4 BYTES WITH BITS = 00XXXXXX 00YYYYYY 00ZZZZZZ ...
* PARM TWO -> 4 BYTES TO RECEIVE BITS = XXXXXXYY YYYYZZZZ ZZ000000 ...
U3856804 CSECT
         SAVE (14,12) "STM 14,12,12(13)"
         USING U3856804,15
         LM 14,15,0(1) R14 -> PARM ONE, R15 -> PARM TWO
         IC 0,0(14)    R0 LOW-ORDER BYTE = 00XXXXXX
         IC 1,1(14)    R1 LOW-ORDER BYTE = 00YYYYYY
         SLL 1,26      R1 HIGH-ORDER BYTE = YYYYYY00
         SLDL 0,6      R0 LOW-ORDER HALFWORD = 0000XXXX XXYYYYYY
         IC 1,2(14)    R1 LOW-ORDER BYTE = 00ZZZZZZ
         SLL 1,26      R1 HIGH-ORDER BYTE = ZZZZZZ00
         SLDL 0,20     R0 = XXXXXXYY YYYYZZZZ ZZZZ.... ........
         ST 0,0(,15)   STORE RESULT
         RETURN (14,12) "LM 14,12,12(13)" "BR 14"
         END
```

Comment: Generally posting just plain code is discouraged - wrap some explanatory text around it.